# C++ WinAPI - sloppy mouse input

Tags: c++, winapi

So, I'm making a game in C++ with OpenGL, and I want my cursor to stay in the middle of the screen.

At the start of each frame I call

```
POINT pt;
pt.x = 400;
pt.y = 300;
ClientToScreen(hWnd, &pt);
SetCursorPos(pt.x, pt.y);
```

Then, on WM_MOUSEMOVE event I do

```
POINT p;
GetCursorPos(&p);
ScreenToClient(hWnd, &p);
dx = p.x - 400;
dy = p.y - 300;
```

The window is 800x600, so I just wrote those numbers, that will be obviously changed later.

It works, but it is very sloppy. Like if some frames would be dropped.

Comment: Don't try and do this.  The mouse and its cursor is a shared resource, and it's not appropriate for individual applications to repeatedly move it.  If you want something which looks like a mouse cursor to appear in the middle of your window, then hide the real cursor and draw what you want where you want it.

Comment: I wanted to contain the cursor in the window, so I can use the move parameters for the camera movement in a first person camera

Comment: You can still do what Will is saying. Hide the cursor but use the mouse move messages to manipulate your camera.

Comment: but then if the mouse goes out of the window, it won't receive any input

Comment: What is the intended way of letting the user rotating the camera to the right, infinitely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`ClipCursor()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to restrict the mouse's movement.  The mouse will not be able to move outside of the specified rectangle until you release it.

Comment: okay, it works, but how should i handle if the mouse is at the borders? i want to rotate too, if it's on the edge. because now if i move outwards the client, and it won't go out, so there is no delta, but i want to rotate the camera

Comment: Make the clip rectangle a little larger then your window, and then use `SetCapture()` to receive mouse messages, like `WM_MOUSEMOVE`  and `WM_LBUTTONUP`, even while the mouse is outside of your window.  Or, just forget `ClipCursor()` and use `SetCapture()` by itself, that way the user has more room to freely move around.  Either way, capture the mouse when the left button is held down on your window, then release capture when the button is released. You can calculate deltas based on movements between messages, or the distance between the mouse message coordinates and your window's coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You could try installing a hook via [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (passing `WH_MOUSE` or maybe even `WH_MOUSE_LL`) and simply discarding all move events before the corresponding window messages even get dispatched.